# How to turn aws opensearch query into java code

Tags: amazon-web-services, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

How to do the aws opensearch query below with java code using aws sdk?

```
POST zipcode-1/_search 
{
  "query": {
    "xy_shape": {
      "geometry": {
        "shape": {
          "type": "point",
          "coordinates": [
            129.47636973396968,
            35.91937013735423
          ]
        },
        "relation": "CONTAINS"
      }
    }
  }
}
```